How to show $\lVert\Delta u_n- \Delta u\rVert_{L^2(0,T; \,H^2(\Omega))} \to 0$ ? $(\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2)$
Let $u_n, \nabla u_n, \Delta u_n, \nabla \Delta u_n, \Delta^2 u_n$ be uniformly bounded in $L^2((0,T) \times \Omega)$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2, u=\Delta u =0$ on $\partial \Omega$.
Assume that $\Omega$ is regular enough so that by regularity estimates $u_n$ is uniformly bounded in $L^2((0,T); H^4(\Omega))$ as well.
Then, the compact embedding $L^2((0,T); H^4(\Omega)) \hookrightarrow  L^2((0,T); H^2(\Omega))$ ensures that $u_n \to u$ up to a subsequence in $L^2((0,T); H^2(\Omega))$.
Is it possible to state $\lVert\Delta u_n- \Delta u\rVert_{L^2(0,T;\, H^2(\Omega))} \rightarrow 0$?

I assume you mean the sequences are uniformly bounded in $L^2((0,T)\times\Omega)$, right?

@ClaraTorres-Latorre yes.

There's no reason for such a strong convergence ; in the periodic setting $\Omega=\mathbf{T}^2$ you can think of $u_n(x) := |n|^{-4}e^{in\cdot x}$ which is indeed uniformly bounded in $H^4(\mathbf{T}^2)$, converges to $0$ (at least) in $H^2(\mathbf{T}^2)$ but $x\mapsto\Delta^2 u_n(x) = e^{in\cdot x}$ does not converge in $L^2(\mathbf{T}^2)$ to $0$.
